# VB.net 2008 using event output from a class in the Form Cross-thread error

Tags: vb.net, delegates, event-handling, invoke

I have a class to handle Serial port for receiving data from Scanner and raise an event when there is data in serial port buffer:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class CommManager
' Here is settings for serial port
    Public Event HaveScannerData(ByVal e As String)
    Private Sub ProcessDataReceived(ByVal DataReceived As String)
        'This sub happens when there is data in the buffer and data is Input_String
            RaiseEvent HaveScannerData(Input_String)
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Then in the form, i want to use this event to show it in a label box. i use:

```
Private WithEvents ScannerPort As New CommManager

Private Sub OnHaveSerialPortData(ByVal Compelete_Data_Received) Handles ScannerPort.HaveScannerData
    Label1.Text = Compelete_Data_Received
End Sub
```

Problem is i get this error message:
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
I know i have to use Invoke and Delegate but i don't know how. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problme in the past. Replace your code in OnHaveSerialPortData with this:

```
If Label1.InvokeRequired Then Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = Compelete_Data_Received) else Label1.Text = Compelete_Data_Received
```

This should handle the label1 text change from either the main thread or a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but Sub() after Invoke is not accepted by VB.net

Comment: That's weird, I've got this in my code and it's called a couple of hundred times and works each and every time. How have you initialised the new threads? Also how many thread do you have running concurrently?

Comment: Also what version of vb.net are you using, I've just re-tested this in 2010 and it seems to work OK. What error do you get when trying to run the code I've suggested?

Comment: emm, i'm using VB.net 2008! i think this cause the problem! because i'm searching on MSDN and the solution is very similar to your solution. i'm working to add a delegate sub to return the address like C++.

Comment: BTW error message is "Expression Expected". Also this program is very simple using just one thread

Comment: Lambda expressions are not supported in earlier versions of Visual Studio.  Using Invoke() is a Really Bad Idea, it deadlocks the program when it calls the serial port's Close() method.  Always use BeginInvoke().

Comment: WOW! thanks man, i'm writing a CORE class for a DLL. deadlock is the worst thing in DLL. Also about Lambda you are right! Again: Thanks for spending time on this :)

Comment: Best Answer:    Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)

    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the'
    ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.'
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.'
    If Me.textBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        Me.textBox1.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub